# Complete non-vanishing vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a non-compact smooth manifold.  Suppose we have a nowhere-vanishing smooth vector field X.  Is this vector field complete?

I know it is when $M$ is compact.  However, I am unsure in the non-compact case.  I asked a friend of mine and he is pretty sure that he has seen that is, but he couldn't remember why this was true.  Could you please explain why it is or is not true.

Note, a vector field is complete if it's flow is global.

I am trying to use the Uniform Time Lemma to prove it but am current failing.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The interval $(-1,1)$ is a smooth manifold, and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ is a nonvanishing field on it, evidently non-complete. Did you want to assume that $M$ itself is complete?

Comment: @user75064 yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M=\mathbb R$ and $X=(x^2+1)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$. Then $M$ is complete, $X$ does not vanish, but every solution of $\varphi '=\varphi^2+1$ blows up in finite time, because it's of the form $\varphi(t)=\tan (t-C)$. Therefore $X$ is not complete.

Comment: is that X a smooth vector field?

Comment: @LeoSpencer It's as smooth as the function $x^2+1$.

Comment: That's right I forgot that was how we detemine smoothness of vector fields was just to look at the coordinate functions.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I am not sure you are right about this.  I don't think it matter that the curve eventually blows up.  All that matters is that we can flow from one point to the other for enough time and get on that next curve and flow on and so forth? @user75064

Comment: @Leo Spencer. That's not the definition of a complete field that I know. Why don't you state yours in the question?

Comment: There now. See above.

Comment: Evidently your two definition agree. What @user75064 has shown is precisely that the flow does not exists for all time. The function $\varphi$ is the flow map for time $t$ for a given point $y$; the freedom in choosing the initial point $y$ is in the constant of integration $C$.

Comment: Willie: you pinged me instead of @Leo (I'd get the notification anyway), so I ping him now.

Comment: @WillieWong I agree I was thinking of something wrong.  Is there a way to fix the issue?  I am working on a problem where I need my vector field to be complete.  Is there a way to rig my current vector field which is non-zero everywhere turning it into one that is complete with a flow that lasts for all time?

Comment: @user75064 I agree now I was thinking of something wrong.  Is there a way to fix the issue?  I am working on a problem where I need my vector field to be complete.  Is there a way to rig my current vector field which is non-zero everywhere turning it into one that is complete with a flow that lasts for all time?

Comment: @LeoSpencer Instead of comments, you could either add your new question via edit to the original post, or just ask another question. My suggestion: multiply the field by a scalar function so that its norm is bounded (or just equal to one). For example, $X$ in my answer would be multiplied by $\|X\|^{-1}=(x^2+1)^{-1}$, making it a unit vector field. Then the flow will have bounded time derivative.

Comment: @LeoSpencer if you just wanted a global flow, then the suggestion above by user75064 does the trick. Note that however the diffeomorphisms induced by the original vector field and the new "renormalised" vector field can be quite different. So if you have other properties that you want preserved, you should ask a new question stating precisely what properties you need.